# CORS error when making call to spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

When I'm making a GET call to spring-cloud-dataflow-server-local from my webapp, I get this error:

**XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:9393/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:7002' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403.**

How can I adjust this?

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We currently have an open issue regarding Cross-Origin (CORS) support:

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-dataflow/issues/1048

We hope to have that addressed for the upcoming RC release.

If you have a client web-application (during development, e.g. Grunt / Gulp etc.), you have to ensure (using proxy plugin) that the Origin header corresponds to the Spring Cloud Data Flow host.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Gunnar, following your tip I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19193914/yeoman-webapp-with-grunt-connect-proxy-not-working) and got the proxy working for my Yo Angular web app